# looping through json data in react hooks state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, react-map-gl

I wanna display the data that I have in my state in a map I managed to get both latitude and longitude in my state the problem is whenever try to map trough the state I always get it's not a function error here's parts of my code and the data that I have in the state:

```
const [countriesData, setCountriesData] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
const fetchAPI = async () => {
  setCountriesData(await fetchDataCountries());
};
fetchAPI();
}, [setCountriesData]);

console.log(countriesData);
```

and mapping through it like this:

```
 {countriesData.map((data)=>(
     <Marker latitude={data.countriesData.latitude}
     longitude={data.countriesData.longitude}/>
     ))}
```

the fetch api function:

```
export const fetchDataCountries = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await axios.get(url);
    const newData = data.data;
    const modfiedData = newData.map((countryData) => {
      return countryData.coordinates;
    });
    return modfiedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code/text in then actual question itself. Not pictures, and definitely not a *link* to a picture

Comment: please bear with me sir as I'm trying to make it properly work thanks

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: sorry sir i just added the code since the images didn't work out

Comment: pay attention to your useEffect usage (it's running the async function everytime it renders)

Answer (score 0):

For your `map` to work you need to convert your`state` to an array, now it is an object.

After that, it could look something like this:

```js
{countriesData.map((country) => (
  <Marker
    latitude={country.latitude}
    longitude={country.longitude}
  />
))}
```

or

```js
{countriesData.map(({ latitude, longitude }) => (
  <Marker
    latitude={latitude}
    longitude={longitude}
  />
))}
```

But for a more accurate answer, it would be nice to have an example of the contents of your `state`.

Comment: the contain a 323 array and inside of each, i have something like this :[0 … 99] and 0:
latitude: "53.9333"
longitude: "-116.5765"
__proto__: Object i wanna use the latitude and longitude in other to display it in the map

Comment: so I think the code above should help you solve your problem

Comment: no it still says CountriesData.mao in not a function

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing the `countriesData` with an empty object, then you're fetching a API data.

Assuming the response is an array of objects like this:

```js
[
   { latitude: 38.8451, longitude: -37.0294 }
   { ... // other coordinates }
]
```

Change the initial state to be an empty array like this:

`const [countriesData, setCountriesData] = useState([]);`

Also, update this block:

```js
{countriesData.map((data) => <Marker latitude={data.latitude} longitude={data.longitude} />)}
```

---

**Explanation:** the `map()` method only works with Arrays `[]` and not with Objects `{}`, therefore when the component was mounted/initialized for the first time, the map method was executed against an object, thus throwing the `map is not a function` error.

Comment: i've try this earlier but still stuck ,my problem is i get 4 call of the useEffect and i managed to use ternary to check if the data exist and use the response as i said is an multiple object were inside of each there an array of object  when i try to use console.log(countriesData[0]) i get  0: {latitude: "53.9333", longitude: "-116.5765"} but i can't go inside of it to use those proprieties

Comment: Having the console.log many times in the useEffect is not really a problem